# Karma hangs at Karma starting

Tags: jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I am new to Karma.  When i run:

```
karma start myconfigfile.js
```

Karma is starting up with chrome, but it hangs at karma starting and nothing more is happening. However i can go into `http://localhost:9876/debug.html` and can see that tests have been running in console. My test is inside  `vendor/Jasmine/spec/PlayerSpec.js`.

Is this the correct way of using karma for testing or are there some more UI-frendly ways?

Because I can see that karma window should look like [this](http://lh4.ggpht.com/-ucIYxPcdf98/Ub89CjxG1rI/AAAAAAAAOPk/Xo5_COrYThk/s1600-h/image%25255B21%25255D.png).

Have anyone had same problem?

here is my config file:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '/',
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    files: [
        'nodejs/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/jasmine.js',
        'nodejs/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/adapter.js',
        'nodejs/node_modules/requirejs/*.js',
        'vendor/Jasmine/spec/PlayerSpec.js',
        'angular/angular.min.js',
        'angular/angular-mocks.js'

    ],
    exclude: [

    ],
    preprocessors: {

    },
    reporters: ['progress'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_DEBUG,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

Comment: Note you can use `karma start myconfigfile.js --single-run` to exit once tests have been run.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Karma is made of two main components: a `server` and a `runner`.

The first one prepare the test environment and spawn the browsers, but is the second one that starts the tests.

To start the server you have to run `karma start`, while for the second one you have to start in a second shell `karma run <configuration_file_path>` - try it and see the tests running.

If you want to start it automatically, just change this line in your config file:

```
  singleRun: true // => is was false
```

At this point Karma will setup the server, run the tests and shutdown when completed.